# Avoid performing Spring @Async task twice at the same time

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, asynchronous, concurrency

I am just learning multithreading in Spring Framework and I don't know how to deal with one case. I have a long-lasting operation and I do not want the user to wait for it to be done, I find out that there is an **@Async** annotation which flag the method as executable asynchronously.

My question is what would be the best way to block this method such that users from the same company cannot perform it on the same time. Being accurate I want to block even performing **analyzeData(...)** and **anlyzeStatistics(...)** by users from the same company on the same time.

I was thinking about using ConcurrentHashMap with user company as key and boolean as value and checking it before performing the operation. I wonder if I'm going in the right direction, or maybe there are other more appropriate options offered by Spring.

```
@Service
public class LongOperationService {

   @Async
   public void analyzeData(User user, List<String> data) {
       boolean operationResult = performLongOperation(data);
       if (opeartionResult) {
           log.info("Long operation ended successfully")
       } else {
           log.error("Long operation failure")
       }
   }

   @Async
   public void analyzeStatistics(User user, List<String> statistics) {
       ...
   }

   private void performLongOperation(List<String> data) {
        // Just for demonstration
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        return true;
   }
}

public class User {
   String username;
   String company;
}
```

Comment: What result should see users from same company? the same result or second user must fail on running operation?

Comment: I wanted to simplify the task, ignoring the fact of returning value so any output I get is logged message. First user is starting ```boolean operationResult = performLongOperation(data);``` and another should not event start the operation, because the first one already started it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Semaphore` to limit number of threads accessing a resource.

Since you want to prevent users from same company to access your analyze function concurrently, you should create semaphore per company:

```
// Init on startup
// Key should be a unique identifier to a company, I assume the `String company` as key, you should adjust as your real requirement
static final Map<String, Semaphore> COMPANY_ENTRANT = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
// for each company
COMPANY_ENTRANT.put(companyId, new Semaphore(1));
```

Now in your service:

```
@Async
public void analyzeData(User user, List<String> data) {
   Semaphore entrant = COMPANY_ENTRANT.get(user.getCompany());
   try {
       entrant.acquire();
       try {
              boolean operationResult = performLongOperation(data);
              if (opeartionResult) {
                  log.info("Long operation ended successfully")
              } else {
                  log.error("Long operation failure")
              }
       } finally {
          entrant.release();
       }

   } catch(InterruptedException e) {
       ...
   }

}
```

If you want a lazy initialization of the `COMPANY_ENTRANT` map, you can use `putIfAbsent`:

```
 Semaphore entrant = COMPANY_ENTRANT.putIfAbsent(user.getCompany(), new Semaphore(1));
```

Comment: `COMPANY_ENTRANT.putIfAbsent` will return `null` if there was no value in map before. `COMPANY_ENTRANT.computeIfAbsent(user.getCompany(), c -> new Semaphore(1))` should work

Comment: in your case two users from same company will run operation one after another

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
private final Set<String> runningOperations = Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<>());
private final Object lock = new Object();

@Async
public void analyzeData(User user, List<String> data) throws Exception {
    synchronized (lock) {
        if (runningOperations.contains(user.company))
            return;
        runningOperations.add(user.company);
    }
    try {
        boolean operationResult = performLongOperation(data);
        if (operationResult) {
            log.info("Long operation ended successfully");
        } else {
            log.error("Long operation failure");
        }
    } finally {
        runningOperations.remove(user.company);
    }
}
```

Comment: The solution with synchronized block may be acceptable, but this is not. Check and add are not atomic.

Comment: @grape_mao I thought that so minimal probability would be enough. Is it good now?